# Swift iOS App - No Console Messages Cannot Make URLSession Call to GraphQL Enpoint

Tags: swift, graphql

I've been trying to get a list of entities from a graphql endpoint but I can't figure it out. Also, the console in my Xcode v13.4 isn't showing anything even though I have some `print()` statements in the code, so that's not helping - I've found where it is at the bottom of the window but it's always blank.

My View to get the data is below, the `DetailView` is the link following a link from the main `ContentView`. the `loadData` function content, I got the code from Postman after testing the graphql call.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

//array of properties
struct Response: Codable {
    var data: Properties
}

struct Properties: Codable {
    var properties: Nodes
}
struct Nodes: Codable {
    var nodes: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    var propertyId: Int
    var title: String
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.propertyId) { property in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(property.title)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
        }
        .task{
            await loadData()
        }
            
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
        
        let parameters = "{\"query\":\"{\\n  properties {\\n    nodes {\\n      title(format: RENDERED)\\n      propertyId\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\",\"variables\":{}}"
        let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://DOMAIN/graphql")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData
        
        do {
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data else {
                    print(String(describing: error))
                    semaphore.signal()
                    return
                }

                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    results = decodedResponse.data.properties.nodes
                }

                semaphore.signal()
                
            }
            
            task.resume()
            semaphore.wait()
            
        } catch {
            print("Invalid data")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The output of the graphql call is

```json
{
    "data": {
        "properties": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "title": "MY TITLE",
                    "propertyId": 00001
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT
Swapped try? for try! as suggested

```swift
if let decodedResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
   results = decodedResponse.data.properties.nodes
}
```

```
error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Response'
```

Comment: Use `try!` instead of `try?`. `try?` will obfuscate all errors. And add the error message to your question if there is any.

Comment: @burnsi - thanks changed and added the error

Comment: Of course you need to get rid of the if statement as `decodedResponse` is not optional anymore. By "error message" i was refering to a runtime error while decoding.

Comment: @burnsi sorry, absolute novice at Swift currently - swapped for the below

let decodedResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
results = decodedResponse.data.properties.nodes

Where would I see runtime errors, my console isn't working :(

Comment: Well your code would crash. Also put some breakpoint in your function and see if they get hit.

Comment: I noticed that you are using `http` instead of the required `https`.  Did you set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" in your Info.plist to allow `http` connection
 to your domain, using "NSExceptionDomains"?

Comment: change `try?` to `do try catch` never `try!`because it will just crash your app of there is a failure, `?` ignores the failure. Also, based on your update I would encourage you too look at the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). It seems like you are missing a lot of the basics. Also change `print("Invalid data")` to `print("Invalid data \(error)")`. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. You have many issues such as `async` and `DispatchSemaphore`

Comment: Got it working - thanks all. I learn quite well by reverse engineering stuff so hopefully, I'll take away a few things here - definitely running before eI can walk with app development but I'm enjoying it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it all working with the below...

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

//array of properties
struct Response: Codable {
    var data: Properties
}

struct Properties: Codable {
    var properties: Nodes
}
struct Nodes: Codable {
    var nodes: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    var propertyId: Int
    var title: String
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    @State private var test = "one"
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.propertyId) { property in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(property.title)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
        }.task{
            await loadData()
        }
        
            
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
        
        let parameters = "{\"query\":\"{\\n  properties {\\n    nodes {\\n      title(format: RENDERED)\\n      propertyId\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\",\"variables\":{}}"
        let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://DOMAIN/graphql")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData
        
        do {
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                
                guard let data = data else {
                    
                    print(String(describing: error))
                    semaphore.signal()
                    return
                }

                let decodedResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                results = decodedResponse.data.properties.nodes

                semaphore.signal()
                
            }
            
            task.resume()
            semaphore.wait()
            
        } catch {
            print("Invalid data \(error)")
        }
        
    }
  
}
```

Much to learn :)

Comment: you mean you changed `http` to `https`, is that what you learned?
You did not learn the important parts, **do not** use `try!`, use `do try catch` as mentioned, and get rid of the `DispatchSemaphore` stuff.

Comment: You can take advantage of the newer [async `data` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data) (called with `await`) to "get rid of the `DispatchSemaphore` stuff" ✌